# Correct way to use "Sign in with LinkedIn" to identify users on my website?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to understand "Sign In with LinkedIn".  I seem to only be grasping part of the picture.

As I understand it, a user signs in with LinkedIn on my website, and LinkedIn returns a unique user identifier to my website.

Somehow I then use that identifer on my website to identifty the user.

But I don't understand - once the end user has seen the identifier, what is to prevent them using directly from then on and never logging in again via LinkedIn?  Must the returned user ID be kept secret, or can it be displayed publicly, for example in a URL?

Also, what is to prevent someone finding someone else's user id and then using it to access my site?

Seems like I'm missing an entire slab of understanding of how the user id returned from LinkedIn is meant to be used, and what issues there are relating to security.

Can someone explain please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer it myself.  It turns out that you can optionally ask the LinkedIn API to also return a cookie which contains a signature.  Return this cookie to your back end server over an HTTPS connected and there you can validate the signature against your own API key.  Voila - you have proven that this is a valid user and you have proven that the users login actually came from LinkedIn rather than being spoofed.

Answer (score 1):

When a user logs in via linkedin, their API will return to you their user ID.  This really isn't a secret, it's simply linkedin telling you that the user on your site has logged in as user with that unique identifier.  You cannot login as another user simply by knowing their linkedin ID - for linkedin's API to return that ID, the user on your site must have logged into linkedin with a username and password.

As long as you can be sure that the API you're accessing really is linkedin's and the response hasn't been intercepted/changed/faked, you can trust that the ID returned by the API is the correct ID of a user on their site and that they have logged in and authenticated as that user.

Basically, you're safe if you're always using linkedin's API to authenticate linkedin users and don't have a form on your site with a prompt to 'enter your linkedin ID to authenticate'.  Even if a user knows another user's ID, they still need their linkedin username/password for the API to return that ID to you.

Do feel free to store the ID returned though to track user preferences/actions.  You can even associate it with a user already in your database and give the user the option to EITHER login with the username/password combo stored in your database (salted/hashed, hopefully) OR via one of the oauth options.

Hopefully that helps clear things up!

*EDITED BASED ON COMMENTS*

One other point of emphasis regarding how you're handling things AFTER the API request.  You can trust that the ID returned by linkedin is correct, but after that point you must also be able to trust that ID stored on your site is still the same thing you got from linkedin. Use something server-side that the user cannot edit to store this ID (like PHP sessions - NOT url arguments).

Comment: Sorry I'm still not really getting it.  So if I want to use LinkedIn for logins to my new site, I follow the instructions and add the "Sign in with LinkedIn" functionality. After user signs in, my web page then holds their user id.  I include this user ID with every request to my server.  At the back end of my website, I check for this user ID on each inbound request.  Requests that do not have a user ID are not signed in and are thus rejected.  Requests that DO have the user ID attached I can trust as being signed in, and I use that user ID in my DB queries to restrict access. Correct?

Comment: Basically everything you said is accurate except for the details of how you're "including this ID on each inbound request".  You can trust that the ID from linkedin is correct, but after that point you must also be able to trust that ID stored on your site is still the same thing you got from linkedin.  Use something server-side that the user cannot edit to store this ID (like PHP sessions) and you're good to go!

It's OK if a user KNOWS their linkedin ID (or someone else's, really - they can probably get that information straight from linkedin anyway), but they CANNOT be allowed to change it.

Comment: So do we need to keep secret the user id that is provided by LinkedIn following signin?  For example would it be a bad idea to create a URL based on the user id eg www.example.org/(linkedinuserid) Would this enable anyone to log in to our application with the linkedinuserid?

Comment: It's not important that you keep it a secret, only that you don't allow the user to change the variable that stores the authentication information.  It'd be the equivalent of assigning IDs based on an auto_increment field in your db, it's not a secret what someone's ID is - just as long as you can't use that ID to somehow login as that user.

www.example.com/(linkedinuserid) is probably fine, as long as it's to view a user's profile and not to authenticate them.  It's easy to find out someone's ID, it's publicly available on their site by searching for a name.

Comment: For example, linkedin uses the ID in their profile URLs - it's no secret.

This is my profile: www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=66785308 .

My linkedin ID is 66785308 .

Comment: I know I'm being thick here but I'm still missing something important.  If "sign in with LinkedIn" returns a user ID which is not a secret, and if I give access to any request containing that user id, then what is to prevent someone else accessing resources on my website simply by attaching that user ID?

Comment: You don't give access to any request containing that user id, you give access to anyone who gets linkedin's API to return that id to you.  A user should not be allowed to pass that id to you directly to authenticate, you always get it from the API.  www.example.com/id can be used to display information associated with a user, not to log them into the site.

Once you get the ID back from linkedin, the user should have no way to change it - use something server-side like PHP sessions (that the user can't access) to store it.

Comment: @rawb: I know you said we can trust Linkedin API when it returns an user ID after authenticating. However, my Javascript handler that calls to login into my own website might be compromise because it is Javascript. For example: A user login with linkedin, his id pass to my callback(id). In this callback, I post to my server telling that the server is authenticated, log him in. If an attacker override the callback, he can easily compromise the system without any problem. Is there any way to prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose after user authenticates with linkedin successfully, 

it redirects to your page http://www.xyz.com/redirect.php.

Now you have code in redirect.php which takes oauth parameters from URL and calls for userid.

```
function getUserID (){
   // code which takes oauth params and calls linked in api with access token 
   //and returns userId of user
   return userID;
}

$userID = getUserID();
```

Now since your have `$userID` , create a session with `$userID` and redirect user to his/her home page. Check for session in home page, if session `$userID` is set , let user open the page , if session is not available, dont show the page and tell them to login first.

Now to your question, how do you think in this approach user can enter `userID` by his/her own ?